# Outlook add-in, dialog API eventHandler not firing

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I'm developing an auth flow for an outlook add-in, and am trying to use the dialog API to communicate between the dialog and the sidepane. However, the messaging does not work, and the **event handler for the received message is never called**.

Both the sidepane and the dialog box are running on https://localhost:3000.

Im testing this with Outlook for the web on Chrome [using a Mac], and I've been through Microsofts documentation.

Sidepane code:

```
let dialog: any;

function processMessage(arg: any) {
  dialog.close();
}

Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
  'https://localhost:3000/testing.html', 
  {height: 35, width: 50},
  (response: any) => {
     dialog = response.value;
     dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage);
  });
```

Dialog page code:

```
Office.initialize = function(reason) {
   Office.context.ui.messageParent(true);
};
```

The dialogAsync callback and ths messageParent function fire ok, though the processMessage function never gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the configuration `displayInIframe: true` solved the issue, though this does not solve the problem for pages that can not be displayed in an iframe.

This is the change:

```
{height: 35, width: 50, displayInIframe: true}
```